# XSL Counter group and confront

Tags: xslt, counter

I have group elements using this expression:

```
count(. | key('products-by-category', CodiceAttivita)[1]) = 1
```

Now I need to confront the number of results and say that if is more than 1 show a block of elements.
I think to do something like that

```
<xsl:if test=" [count(. | key('products-by-category', CodiceAttivita)[1]) = 1] > 1">
```

But it doesn't work.
How can I fix it?
Thank you

Part of xml is

```
<Riepilogo>
    <IVA>
        <AliquotaIVA>4.00</AliquotaIVA>
        <Imposta>5830.98</Imposta>
    </IVA>
    <Ammontare>145879.00</Ammontare>
    <ImportoParziale>145774.50</ImportoParziale>
    <TotaleAmmontareResi>0.00</TotaleAmmontareResi>
    <CodiceAttivita>253000</CodiceAttivita>
</Riepilogo>
<Riepilogo>
    <IVA>
        <AliquotaIVA>10.00</AliquotaIVA>
        <Imposta>645.66</Imposta>
    </IVA>
    <Ammontare>6587.00</Ammontare>
     <ImportoParziale>6456.60</ImportoParziale>
    <CodiceAttivita>433100</CodiceAttivita>
</Riepilogo>
<Riepilogo>
    <IVA>
        <AliquotaIVA>22.00</AliquotaIVA>
        <Imposta>618.34</Imposta>
    </IVA>
    <Ammontare>3254.85</Ammontare>
     <ImportoParziale>2810.65</ImportoParziale>
    <CodiceAttivita>253000</CodiceAttivita>
</Riepilogo>
```

What I need is group for `CodiceAttivita` and define the case when the `CodiceAttivita` has the same value.

Comment: What is "the number of results"? The number of groups or the number of products in a group? --- Please show a [mcve]  that includes an input XML, an XSLT and the expected output.

Comment: Add code part. thanks

Comment: You did not answer my question. And "code part" is not a [mcve].